# How To Create Sessions Naming After The Mysql Table Columns Names?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having to copy & paste this long list of sessions on every page like home.php, notices_list.php, histories.php, make_post.php, edit_post.php, etc.
I need to cut short on this code so each file size shortens.

I made the session variables labelled after my MySQL table column names, therefore if I write a peace of code for the script to grab the column names and then create the sessions based on the column names then the code would shorten a lot on each page. Thus my web server would be less CPU busy.

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php 

$id = $_SESSION["id"]; 
$email = $_SESSION["email"]; 
$username = $_SESSION["username"]; 
$first_name = $_SESSION["first_name"]; 
$surname = $_SESSION["surname"]; 
$gender = $_SESSION["gender"]; 
$dob = $_SESSION["date_of_birth"]; 
$religion = $_SESSION["religion"]; 
$education = $_SESSION["education"]; 
$profession = $_SESSION["profession"]; 
$state = $_SESSION["state"]; 
$country = $_SESSION["country"];    
}

?>
```

Here are my attempts:

1.

```
<?php 

$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM browsing_histories";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$$row['Field'] =  $_SESSION["$row['Field']"]."<br>";
}

?>
```

Another attempt:
2.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM browsing_histories";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$$row['Field'] =  $_SESSION["\$row['Field']\"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Bear in mind that, since the column names are like this: id, username, gender.

Then currently I got on my lengthy file, the sessions written like this:

```
<?php 
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$gender = $_SESSION["gender"];
?>
```

I don't want to be writing lines of sessions like this to make the file size smaller and so need to write code so script fetches the column names and creates session variables under those fetched column names (or fetched labels or fetched fields).
In short, on the above mentioned lengthy code, you see a variable named "id" and you see a session name "id". I don't want to be typing all this "id" here since it is a column name and I want the script to auto write the column name.
Best, to create array values from the column name and so how to do that as well?

Again, I don't want to be typing all these 'id' and so want the script to write them by grabbing the column field name since here the column field name is 'id'. You know what I want to do. And so, care to show a code sample how to do it?
I need a sample in procedural style using mysqli. Not in to pdo or oop yet.

EDIT:
1st attempt failed:

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
${$row['Field']} = $_SESSION["{$row['Field']}"]."<br>";
}
```

2nd attempt failed:

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$row = $_SESSION["{$row['Field']}"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `include 'file.php';` or `require 'file.php';`

Comment: Check my last code snippet in my original post!
Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather see a code sample RiggsFolly as I am still confused. remember, I'm still a php beginner and a beginner programmer altogether too!

Comment: There is absolutely no need to move session variables into scalar equivalents. Use the session variable directly, but check they exist before using them with a `isset()` so you dont accidentally try an use a session variable that does not exist

Comment: Last try would work : https://eval.in/983310, may be issue is on another side

Comment: Why did not my 1st attempt work ? See my original post.
I get errors:

Notice: Undefined index: date_&_time in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\grab_column_names.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: account_activation_code in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\grab_column_names.php on line 6

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a extra $$ infront of your $$row variable

Comment: I did that deliberate Earnes Aguilera.

Comment: Reading this now:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

But, I would appreciate any code samples from you guys for my learning purpose!